# If $A,B,C$ are sets, show some equalities

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A,B,C$ are sets, show that:

1. $(A\cap B)\cap C=A\cap (B\cap C)$
2. $(A \cap B)\cup C = (A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C)$
3. $(A-B)\cap C=(A\cap C)-(B\cap C)$.

I am starting to work with sets, so I would like to ask you to show me the third example and I'll try to solve the others by myself. I don't have an idea how to start. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that $X=Y$ in general, one way is to show that $x\in X$ implies $x\in Y$, as well as the other way round. In other words, show that $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq X$.

For the third case, suppose $x\in(A-B)\cap C$. This means that $x\in A$, $x\notin B$, and $x\in C$. Since $x\notin B$, then $x\notin B\cap C$, meanwhile $x\in A$ and $x\in C$ implies $x\in A\cap C$. Therefore we know that $x\in (A\cap C)-(B\cap C)$. The other way around is the same: if $x\in (A\cap C)-(B\cap C)$, then $x\in A\cap C$ so that $x\in A$ and $x\in C$, but $x\notin B\cap C$, so that $x\notin B$. This implies $x\in (A-B)\cap C$, as you can check.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I appreciate it. I am not sure I understand how you got $x \in A, x \notin B, x\in C$ from $x\in (A-B)\cap C$?

Comment: We must have $x\in(A-B)$ and $x\in C$. Since $x\in A-B$, then it must be in $A$, but not in $B$, since if it were in $B$ then it would not be in the set difference $A-B$.

Comment: Why $x\in (A-B)$ AND $x\in C$? Isn't it possible to have this equality if $x\in C$ and $x\notin (A-B)$?

Comment: If $x\in D\cap E$, then $x\in D$ and $x\in E$, by definition. This is just the case $D=A-B$ and $E=C$.

Comment: I am not sure you are right. Let us have $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{4,5,6\}$, then $A \cap B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. $x=4\in A\cap B$, but $x\notin A$.

Comment: No, that is $A\cup B$, the **union** of the two sets. The **intersection** of those two sets is $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: Oh, my fault. I am sorry.

Comment: I got the way. Thank you! Why should we show the other way too?

Comment: No problem. To show $X=Y$, you have to show $X\subseteq Y$ (i.e. $x\in X$ implies $x\in Y$) as well as $Y\subseteq X$, otherwise there could be some $y\in Y$ that is not in $X$, and then they wouldn't be equal sets although $X\subseteq Y$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you hive me a hint for the second problem? There are unions, so I am not sure how to solve it. I did the first one. :)

Comment: Are you here? :)

Comment: Hi, for unions the idea is the same, except that you replace "and" with a "or". So if $x\in(A\cap B)\cup C$, then either $x\in A$ and $x\in B$, or $x\in C$ (or both). In each of these two cases, show that $x$ is in both $A\cup C$ and $B\cup C$, so that $x\in(A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C)$.